# VS 2017 Go To Implementation does not show method implementation in .NET Core

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

i am newbie for .NET Environment. What i want is when i ctrl + left click a method (eg Join method in String class) i want to see complete source code of that method but i have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVysm.png)

I want to something like this : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c

It works with .NET standard but in .NET Core i can't see source codes. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a decompiler to do this.

Try this free tool.

https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/